# What is wrong with the MOSFET in this spice simulation?

Tags: mosfet, kicad, ngspice

I am trying to simulate the circuit in KiCad pictured in this post.
[image]
It keeps coming up with the error

```
doAnalyses: TRAN:  Timestep too small; initial timepoint: trouble with node "xu1.37"
run simulation(s) aborted
```

I say it is a problem with the MOSFET becuase when I remove it and short all its connections the simulation runs.

I am using the default NMOS spice model in KiCad right now, but have downloaded another spice model and had similar results.

I am just starting to do spice simulations so please ask me for more information if I left some important info out.

Comment: Try replacing the opamp. Try alternate solver.

Comment: Try setting the timestep to a small value say 10ns using a simulation command.

Comment: The opamp is powered from only 2.7V but its maximum output might only go as high as 2V less than its supply voltage (+0.7V) which is much too small to turn on a Mosfet that might need 10V Vgs to turn on.

Comment: What exact mosfet are you using? By default, the NMOS element is representative of what you’d find in an IC process, not as a discrete part.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Seeting the timestep lower did work to run the simulation thank you @RussellH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> doAnalyses: TRAN:  Timestep too small; initial timepoint: trouble with node "xu1.37"
> run simulation(s) aborted

Setting the time timestep to a small value should work.